# What is the intuition of lower global bases?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, quantum-groups, intuition

In the paper: Crystallizing the Q-analogue of Universal Enveloping Algebras, Kashiwara introduced the upper global bases. In the paper: https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1077295931, Kashiwara introduced lower global bases. What is the intuition of lower global basis? Thank you very much.